# How far back can you collect Twitter data on Rstudio?

Tags: r, twitter

I've been able to collect tweets containing a specific text from the previous 6-9 days, but I would like to collect data from much further back if possible. I've also ran into the issue when the dataset is large I'll receive a rate limit. I was told that using RSelenium might help bypass either of these issues. If you know of a way to collect Twitter data past 6-9 days or a way to implement a rest period when collecting a large amount of twitter data in order to work around the rate limit, that would be much appreciated.

Comment: Limits that an API imposes are an issue for the API; if you find a distinct problem, SO is a good place for them, but questions specific to API limits are appropriate for those that provide the API. *"using RSelenium might help bypass"* ... please be careful, "bypass" sounds like usurping the end-user agreement (e.g., https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/rate-limiting, as you probably already have read).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twitter has several search APIs, and the one that rTweet uses by default is the standard search API which does indeed reach back about 6-9 days. I believe that there's a branch of rTweet that supports the premium search APIs which can cover 30-days or the full opus, but you need to opt-in to those APIs, and the rate limits are low unless you move into the paid tiers.

You could try to build something using RSelenium but the Twitter platform TOS and Developer Policy exclude permission to web-scrape outside of the standard robots.txt rules.

Efforts to "work around the rate limit" e.g. multiple apps for the same use case, are not things you should be looking to do, as Twitter could deny your apps or server.